# Is there any way to show preview of pdf, docx, image, excel and other type of files selected in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> I am currently creating a chat application with file upload betwwen two users, Is there any way to show a preview or when a file is uploaded show the file preview rather than showing the url in react ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-viewer, it supports Images: png, jpeg, gif, bmp, including 360-degree images
pdf
csv
xslx
docx
Video: mp4, webm
Audio: mp3
Probably you are looking for some existing package(s).